# deploy 100 vm in GCP (with same configuration at same time)

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I wanted to deploy the 100 VM for my customer as he want.But i dont want to create the 100 VM manually one by one . i wanted to create those VMs in single time in single click .Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969240/script-to-create-multiple-gce-vms-simultaneously) post, there is a feature for creating instances, named [instance templates.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/) The latter lets you configure the instance’s properties, to be used in a managed group of Virtual Machines (VM) or individual VMs.

Quoting the documentation:

> “An [Instance Group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) is a collection of virtual machine (VM)
>   instances that you can manage as a single entity.”

It contains identical instances that are based on an instance template. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances), you may find the instructions on how to create it.

When I tried to reproduce as an example (from the linked documentation), first I created an Instance Template with this command:

> gcloud compute instance-templates create example-template-custom
>   --machine-type n1-standard-4 --image-family debian-9  --image-project debian-cloud --boot-disk-size 250GB

And then when I executed this command:

> gcloud compute instance-groups managed create example-group
>   --base-instance-name test --size 3 --template example-template-custom

to create the Instance Group, 3 VMs have been created in my GCP Console with the names:

test-j1wl

test-ksg6

test-ps1b

on the region I specified from the Shell.

Alternatively, you can use Terraform to manage your GCP VM instances in a corresponding way, as stated in [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance_group_manager.html).